# My dreamweaver doesn't work right

Tags: php, dreamweaver, wampserver

I'm a true beginner in php. I installed wampserver and adobe dreamweaver. I tried to write some codes to understand php, but it doesn't work right. My code is here;

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>function testing</TITLE>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-9">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1254">
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<?php
function sum1 ($num1, $num2) {$result = $num1 + $num2; return $result;}
function sub1 ($num1, $num2) {$result = $num1 - $num2; return $result;}
$num1 = 12; $num2 = 5;
print sum1($num1, $num2); print ("<br>"); print sub1($num1, $num2); print ("<br>");
?>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I tried to run and i just see that in my browser;

```
"); print sub1($num1, $num2); print (" "); ?>
```

what do you suggest me to fix this problem? Thanks in advance..

Comment: print sub1($num1, $num2); isn't even in the code you posted above - you had print sub($num1, $num2);. That's 'sub' without the 1 at the end. Are you sure you're not running a different script?

Comment: If you're a true beginner you shouldnt be using IDEs. They hide too much detail to be helpful in the long run.

Comment: Is your wamp server running? What do you see when you type `http://localhost` to the location bar of your browser? PHP can't work if you open your page directly from your desktop.

Comment: You should view the page in your browser through `http://localhost/...`. If you see `file://...` in the browser address bar then what you're seeing is correct, although not what you're expecting.

Comment: Also, double check that your file is saved as `<whatever>.php`, not `<whatever>.html` or `<whatever>.php.html`.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to start from the scratch follow this site: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/

it is simply great, i have learnt my basics from here .

For your instant solution i have something for you:

1.install wamp from here:http://www.wampserver.com/
2.install it
3.a tray icon will appear
4.right click it start the server
5.open a notepad ,type your code ,save as "myfirsttry.php" (with qoutes)
6.copy this file and paste it in wamp/www folder
7.again go to the tray icon launch the browser from there

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your server doesn't recognize the > of `print("<br>")` to be the closing part of the php-tag. This is due to the server not knowing how to handle your php-tag.

Hope this helps you

Comment: does it work correctly if uninstall wampserver and than install again?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use parenthesis aroud function calls?
And function names are differents.

Anyway it's recommended to use [echo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) which allow to forget parenthesis among others.

Comment: So whether your server is inactive, or your file has no extension php.

Comment: i think my problem with server

Comment: What's your wampserver icon color?

Comment: i think light yellow and when my cursor above the wampserver icon all services are running seen me

Comment: icon should be white, I think other service is running on your port 80. Check it (Apache -> Service).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your file isn't being handled as a php file, check the server logs and make sure you have php enabled in your apache.

And as a side note, oh dear god the uglyness of uppercase tag names is killing my eyes, and why in the world are you using 2 content-type tags?

Please check [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WSc78c5058ca073340dcda9110b1f693f21-7bdda.html) and [this](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/dreamweaver/) to produce valid (x)html code from dreamweaver.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have defined function with name of sum1 an sub1 and calling it via sum and sub respectively.

So, your browser is not displaying output but its showing error..

Try out following.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>function testing</TITLE>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-9">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1254">
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<?php
function sum1 ($num1, $num2) {$result = $num1 + $num2; return $result;}
function sub1 ($num1, $num2) {$result = $num1 - $num2; return $result;}
$num1 = 12; $num2 = 5;
print sum($num1, $num2); print ("<br>"); print sub($num1, $num2); print ("<br>");
?>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Thanks!

Hussain

Comment: In your example you named the functions sum1 and sub1 but you're calling them as sub() and sum(), please check it again.